# Response Buffer Limit Exceeded for certain users

Tags: asp-classic

I'm editing a classic ASP website and previously I was getting an error of "Response Buffer Limit Exceeded" when the code was trying to redirect to a different page with variables being passed through via the URL.

I later found that this was being caused by one of the variables having no value, and so after fixing that the error no longer appeared. However it recently came to light that the error was still appearing in certain situations, again where this specific variable value wasn't available. In this case though it only seems to be occurring for specific users, for example I've seen the error happen to someone else, but when I try the same thing it doesn't happen.

Are there any settings or anything that could be impacting this on a per user basis? Or is it just coincidence that some are getting this while others aren't?

**UPDATE...**

I've put in some code below that is setting the page to redirect to. It is taking values from the current page query string and placing them in variables. The variable that was previously causing problems was the last one (var_search). When a button is pressed it encodes the page path and passes it to a different piece of code.

After that code has finished it's tasks it then does a Response.Redirect with the given URL, and it's at this point that it returns the error.

```
this_page = "auth.asp?type=" & var_type & "&frm_page_title=" & var_page_title & "&frm_date_from=" & var_date_from & "&frm_date_to=" & var_date_to & var_all_views & "&frm_report=" & var_report & "&frm_search=" & var_search

Server.URLEncode(this_page)
```

Comment: You may want to share some code of the offending page, or a small snippet of code the replicates the issue.

Comment: And is the error occurring on the calling page or the called page?  I suspect that it is the called page and so the issue is the logic what you do when a parameter is empty is not there and you are retrieving way too many rows of data, have response.buffer = true and not enough response.flush statements.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yeah from what I can tell it is the called page that is generating the error. I'll try adding some flush statements into the code and seeing how that impacts on things. Any ideas why it might only be occurring for some users?